# Magento 2 : Redirect customer to login page on email change

Tags: module, customer, event-observer, redirect

i want to redirect the customer to the login page when email id is changed from edit form ,i did below code

**Issues :**

```
1:  I am not getting redirected to login page, i can see message **Please Login now** also it show error message **customer could not be saved** where are details are getting saved.

2: I see below error :
Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\Magento\Observer\Customer\SaveObserver::$resultFactory
```

Please help me with same , should i write redirect code in afterExecute ?

**My code as below**

1: Observer

```
<event name="customer_account_edited">
    <observer name="customereditdone" instance="Vendor\Magento\Observer\Customer\SaveObserver" />
</event>
```

2: Observer code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Magento\Observer\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class SaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $_customerGroup;

     protected $_messageManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */ 
     public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        
        
        $customer = $observer->getEvent();
        $email=$customer->getData('email');
        $cid=$customer->getData('entity_id');
        $oldemail = "" // get old email
        
    if($oldemail!=$email){
    
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Please Login now');      
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl("customer/account/login/");
         return $resultRedirect;
        
    }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please study the code in this file EditPost.php
This file will be executed when a person tries to edit the email (temlates/form/edit.phtml) from this file. 
/var/www/html/development_m241/m241/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
then you can redirect it to login page by modifying the code at .. (line 219)

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the account information.'));
                //return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account');
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
```

You can change original vendor folder or may edit this controller in your custom module of module-customer. 

Vibhore